# module 'statsmodels.stats.api' has no attribute 'proportion'

Tags: python

Thank you for reading my question first.

I was running the following code in Juypter Notebook. It worked the first day, but the second day when I tried again, it showed the error "AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.stats.api' has no attribute 'proportion'".  Here are the code:

****import numpy as np

import statsmodels.api as sm

import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

sm.stats.proportion.proportion_confint(0, 60, alpha=0.05, method='binom_test')****

I tried to "pip uninstall Statsmodels" under terminal, but it returned "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" as shown below:

**>>> pip install statsmodels
File "", line 1
pip install statsmodels
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

I tried to run in Pycharm, after install numpy, stats models, it still does not work.

Any explanation why it worked the first day, but not the after that? I also restored my laptop.

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

try `sm.stats.proportion_confint`

The functions from `stats.proportions` are included in `stats` but the module itself is not.

Or, import the module directly. In that case it imports the required functions and not almost all of statsmodels which happens when `import statsmodels.api as sm` is used.

```
from statsmodels.stats import proportion
proportion.proportion_confint(...)
```

Or import module with an alias (my preferred way)

```
import statsmodels.stats.proportion as smprop
smprop.proportion_confint(...)
```

Some explanations are at
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/api-structure.html